# set background color in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, background

I have been trying to figure this out but it seems no matter how hard I try, I cannot seem to get it right. I have a mapview with the coordinates of the shape of a star. The star changes color on hover and opens a link on click. How do you set the background color? (not on hover color, i got that. just the main. Code:

```
for (var country in onestar) {
    var obj = r.path(onestar[country].path);

    obj.attr(attributes);

    arr[obj.id] = country;



    obj
    .hover(function(){


    this.animate({
            fill: '#41464e'
        }, 300);
    }, function(){
        this.animate({
            fill: attributes.fill
        }, 300);
    })
    .click(function(){


    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com/')


    });

    $('.point').find('.close').live('click', function(){
        var t = $(this),
            parent = t.parent('.point');

        parent.fadeOut(function(){
            parent.remove();
        });
        return false;
    });


}
```

Everything I try I just get errors. :(

Comment: Could you provide the full code, preferably in a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: What you seem to be doing is not a standard DOM thing. Is this a Raphael app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('your selector').css('background-color','your color');
```

should do it.

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [jquery ui 1.9+](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)  then try using `backgroundColor` instead of `fill`

Comment: +1 for mentioning [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) as its an add-on to the standard [jQuery API](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: I mention it because it looks like he is using some version of the jQueryUI. v1.9+ now allows you to animate between background colours.